# Why is the answer "a clean take-off" instead of "a secure take-off"?

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

> *Which of the following is the most suitable to replace the blank space?*
> **The pilot managed to make a _____ take-off during the inclement storm.**
>
> (a) right
> (b) clean
> (c) correct
> (d) secure

Why is the answer "b" in the answer guide?
"Clean" gives the same meaning as "accurate" as in the Oxford dictionary.
Why isn't the answer "d"?

Comment: Wow, this is hard, because "d" isn't obviously wrong, although "b" sounds better.  I'm not sure I love this workbook. The example isn't phrased very well; the sentence would sound much better without "to make." People don't say "make a take-off."

Comment: Also, _inclement storm_ is a tautology.

Comment: It seems to me that any of b,c or d could be correct. But which of the three would seem to have more to do with a knowledge of aviation jargon than basic English.

Comment: I don't know whether they expect you to already know idiom for this, but clean is the only idiomatic word that fits. Clean landing is idiomatic too. None of the others are, even if they may make sense. Safe would work, but that wasn't on offer. Clean is the one, even if there was no word list to choose from.

Comment: To my mind, **secure** describes a state rather than a event.

Comment: Secure does not describe a take off very well.  *Secure* is a feeling.  *Secure* might describe the passengers but not the *takeoff*.  Planes destined for Disney World do not make *excited* takeoffs.

Comment: @EllieK "A secure take off" sounds idiomatic to me.  *Bird control is an essential part of ensuring secure take off and landing at any airport*.

Comment: @EllieK: Secure can be an objective evaluation as well as an emotional one e.g. "the funding has been secured; the building is secure", so it depends on the circumstances. I could quite see the term being used transitively to describe a take off or landing from a secure location (since take off and landing are when an aircraft are most vulnerable to attack, due to low speed and altitude). A take off from a major international airport sounds secure; one from a makeshift runway in a conflict zone does not.

Comment: @WS2 & sharur - Good points and I agree.  I was looking for faults with *secure*, in an effort to show why *clean* was the better choice.  I would certainly understand what someone meant if they referenced a *secure take-off*.  Perhaps I went too far.

Answer (score 4):

"Clean take off" is the jargon that pilots use.  The others are understandable and grammatically correct (although "right take off" would be very odd).

The idea being tested is, "Do you know the idiom?".  It is the same kind of question as "It's raining ....."  a) hard b) strongly c) much d) lots.

Comment: e) cats and dogs f) sideways f) like stair rods… ;))

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary.com also has the following definition for "clean":
19 free from defects or flaws:

which is the sense being sought here.

Comment: More to the point, it's the only idiomatic one offered in the list. Not sure whether a learner at that particular level is supposed to already know that - we have no background to the question.